# App inventor: PhoneNumberPicker and sending SMS

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm doing a geolocalization app which finds my position and then sends an SMS to a number in my address book. When I try to send the message, an "invalid destinationAddress" error occurs. Where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: show your code to send sms

Comment: show me you code, then i'll try to figure out problem

Comment: Did you see the link?

Comment: Ok, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `PhoneNumberPicker.GotFocus` event you should use the `PhoneNumberPicker.AfterPicking` event. Also remove the `PhoneNumberPicker.Open` block. Your list of phone numbers will automatically open after clicking your button (here the Phone Number Picker component).

[image]

Also make sure, you have a valid address before sending the SMS. The Location sensor needs a few seconds until a location is available. You can find several threads about this in the [App Inventor Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/location$20sensor%7Csort:date).

And: you might want to use the `join` block to join `Latitude`, `Longitude` and `CurrentAddress` to send... in your example each time you are overwriting the message to be sent and in the end you are sending only `CurrentAddress` ...

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the
 [Top 5 Tips: How to learn  App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Comment: Thank for the help Taifun